# Can't install package (remove symfony/symfony No version set)

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I tried to install a new package to my project but I got this error :

> Problem 1
>       - The requested package symfony/var-dumper (locked at v3.4.22, required as ^4.3@dev) is satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v3.4.22] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     Problem 2
>       - Installation request for symfony/symfony No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
>       - cmen/google-charts-bundle dev-master requires symfony/framework-bundle ^2.7 || ^3.0 || ^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v3.4.22, 2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev, 3.1.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev, 3.3.x-dev, 3.4.x-dev, 4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, 4.3.x-dev

.....

> don't install symfony/framework-bundle 2.7.x-dev|remove
>   symfony/symfony No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)

I then tried to update but I get the same error message. Anything I do with composer gives me the same error..

Here is my composer.json file :

```
{
    "name": "symfony/symfony",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "The Symfony PHP framework",
    "keywords": ["framework"],
    "homepage": "https://symfony.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Fabien Potencier",
            "email": "fabien@symfony.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Symfony Community",
            "homepage": "https://symfony.com/contributors"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "doctrine/collections": "~1.0",
        "doctrine/event-manager": "~1.0",
        "doctrine/persistence": "~1.0",
        "fig/link-util": "^1.0",
        "twig/twig": "^1.35|^2.4.4",
        "psr/cache": "~1.0",
        "psr/container": "^1.0",
        "psr/link": "^1.0",
        "psr/log": "~1.0",
        "psr/simple-cache": "^1.0",
        "symfony/contracts": "^1.0.2",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "~1.8",
        "symfony/polyfill-intl-icu": "~1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-intl-idn": "^1.10",
        "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "~1.5",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.2",
        "symfony/asset": "^4.2",
        "symfony/form": "^4.2",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.2",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.2",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "^1.8",
        "mukadi/chartjs-builder": "dev-master",
        "cmen/google-charts-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/asset": "self.version",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "self.version",
        "symfony/cache": "self.version",
        "symfony/config": "self.version",
        "symfony/console": "self.version",
        "symfony/css-selector": "self.version",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "self.version",
        "symfony/debug": "self.version",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "self.version",
        "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "self.version",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "self.version",
        "symfony/dotenv": "self.version",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "self.version",
        "symfony/expression-language": "self.version",
        "symfony/filesystem": "self.version",
        "symfony/finder": "self.version",
        "symfony/form": "self.version",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "self.version",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "self.version",
        "symfony/http-kernel": "self.version",
        "symfony/inflector": "self.version",
        "symfony/intl": "self.version",
        "symfony/ldap": "self.version",
        "symfony/lock": "self.version",
        "symfony/messenger": "self.version",
        "symfony/mime": "self.version",
        "symfony/monolog-bridge": "self.version",
        "symfony/options-resolver": "self.version",
        "symfony/process": "self.version",
        "symfony/property-access": "self.version",
        "symfony/property-info": "self.version",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "self.version",
        "symfony/routing": "self.version",
        "symfony/security": "self.version",
        "symfony/security-core": "self.version",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "self.version",
        "symfony/security-guard": "self.version",
        "symfony/security-http": "self.version",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "self.version",
        "symfony/serializer": "self.version",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "self.version",
        "symfony/templating": "self.version",
        "symfony/translation": "self.version",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "self.version",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "self.version",
        "symfony/validator": "self.version",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "self.version",
        "symfony/var-exporter": "self.version",
        "symfony/web-link": "self.version",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "self.version",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "self.version",
        "symfony/workflow": "self.version",
        "symfony/yaml": "self.version"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "cache/integration-tests": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/annotations": "~1.0",
        "doctrine/cache": "~1.6",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.4,>=2.4.5",
        "doctrine/reflection": "~1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "monolog/monolog": "~1.11",
        "ocramius/proxy-manager": "~0.4|~1.0|~2.0",
        "predis/predis": "~1.1",
        "egulias/email-validator": "~1.2,>=1.2.8|~2.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~3.4|~4.0",
        "symfony/security-acl": "~2.8|~3.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.11",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^3.0|^4.0",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^4.3@dev"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "<3.0||>=3.2.0,<3.2.2",
        "phpdocumentor/type-resolver": "<0.3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "<5.4.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\": "src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/",
            "Symfony\\Bridge\\Monolog\\": "src/Symfony/Bridge/Monolog/",
            "Symfony\\Bridge\\ProxyManager\\": "src/Symfony/Bridge/ProxyManager/",
            "Symfony\\Bridge\\Twig\\": "src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/",
            "Symfony\\Bundle\\": "src/Symfony/Bundle/",
            "Symfony\\Component\\": "src/Symfony/Component/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "src/Symfony/Component/Intl/Resources/stubs"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/Tests/"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "files": [ "src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "src/Symfony/Contracts"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "4.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

I probably broke it at some point but I have absolutely no idea how to fix this. Do you have any clue ?

=> Edit : It must come from the json file. I deleted the vendor folder and the composer.lock, installed a fresh version of composer and I have the same problem. Maybe I moved something I don't know

=>Edit2 : Took off all the "replace" lines and now I have this :

> Using version ^1.5@dev for twig/extensions ./composer.json has been
>   updated Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could
>   not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/event-manager 1.0.x-dev
>       - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/event-manager 1.0.x-dev
>       - doctrine/event-manager v1.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/common[v2.7.3].
>       - doctrine/event-manager v1.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/common[v2.7.3].
>       - Installation request for doctrine/event-manager ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/event-manager[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0].
>       - Installation request for doctrine/common (installed at v2.7.3) -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[v2.7.3].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

Comment: Why do you have so many packages list under the `replace` section? `replace` means that your own source code provides these packages. That is probably not what you want to do, right?

Comment: @xabbuh yeah I don't know where those lines came from.. I took them off but still get some errors. I edited my post

Comment: I updated composer and seems to works now